# TypeError: $(...).mask is not a function by jquery in asp.net c#

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I am doing one task in that I am doing jquery masked for date but when I am running this task in html it work very well but in asp.net it shows the issues that is mask is not a function.

here is my code

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.14.10/jquery.mask.js"></script>

<asp:Label ID="Label4" Text="Birth Date :" runat="server"></asp:Label>&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="text" id="date"/>

$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#date').mask("99/99/9999");
    });
```

Thank You.

Comment: convert it to a snippet here it's working fine. :(

Comment: You need to post the view-source of the example - if the issue is client side, we cannot tell you when you post server side code. Perhaps the ASP is renaming the input or removing the js library

Comment: The mask input worked fine on JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/p12d3c5b/. Either jQuery is not loaded properly from CDN, or something went missing on your ASPX page then.

Comment: this is the only code which I done in asp.net at design side

Answer (score 0):

This may causes two scenario one is your server may slow to fetch the mask plugin from cdn, to avoid this access the file from local. second one is you placed that on ready function, sometimes ready function execute before the js file load. So change ready function to onload function or try with some setTimeout function but it is not correct way, setTimeout function helps to identify the second scenario issue.